# Dockerize laravel application using laradock

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile, docker-image, laradock

I am new to Docker and I am trying to implement a laravel project using docker.I successfully run that project using Docker.

But I am in trouble with building that project or dockerize that. I have done some digging for dockerize laravel project but none of them use Laradock.

I have confusion with writing dockerfile which will be necessary for Dockerize projcet.

Any suggestion or tutorial related to dockerize laravel along with Laradock and writing docker file will be really helpful.

Comment: I wrote a tutorial for getting started with Docker and Laravel, which starts you out with a simple Docker setup https://bitpress.io/simple-approach-using-docker-with-php/

Comment: Write down exactly what you need out of the project. You have your Laravel app and you need to have it available in Docker, meaning you need nginx, php-fpm and mysql (or mariadb).
Follow Paul's tutorial, to see if you can make it work.
Write down exactly what you're running in to. Have your docker-compose.yml ready and let's see if the tutorial helps you plenty.

Answer (score 3):

Laradock is only for development as stated in their website. Dockerizing the app for production, you need to have a `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look [this article](https://medium.com/@shakyShane/laravel-docker-part-1-setup-for-development-e3daaefaf3c). It describes how to "dockerize" application which uses `nginx/php-fpm` and `mysql`. Example provided on laravel.

Also will be good to understand [what is Docker and how it works](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/).